# Create 2 tables in a single greendao database?

Tags: database, greendao

Hi i am implementing Greendao db but I want to create 2 tables in a single DB. So I wanted to know is it possible to create? Because I am not getting the output.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you provide your GreenDao generator code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

///////////////////////////////////sample///////////////////////////////////////

```
    Entity person = schema.addEntity("Person");
    person.addIdProperty();
    person.addStringProperty("name");
    person.addStringProperty("comment");

    Entity lease = schema.addEntity("Lease");
    lease.addIdProperty();
    lease.addStringProperty("item");
    lease.addStringProperty("comment");
    lease.addLongProperty("leasedate");
    lease.addLongProperty("returndate");

    Property personId = lease.addLongProperty("personId").getProperty();
    lease.addToOne(person, personId);

    ToMany personToLease = person.addToMany(lease, personId);
    personToLease.setName("leases");

    new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../app/src/main/java");
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Find more details here 
http://www.devteam83.com/en/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-1/